# nested models best practice - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-attributes

Suppose I have two models `model1` and `model2`, and that `model2` belongs_to `model1` (conversely, `model1` has many `model2`). Suppose now I want to create a `model2`, from the `model1/1` page view, (the page showing the `model1` with id 1).  Here's what I did :

```
<%= form_for(@model2, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
      <%= f.submit "POST" %>
<% end %>
```

(@model2 was instantiated in the `model1` controller show method). Is this a best practice ? Should I use nested attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What CDub said is right. However you can achieve the nested CRUD resources this way:

user = model1
post = model2

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In your routes you can do this:

```
routes.rb

resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

and in your posts controller you can do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.new
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      redirect_to user_posts_path(current_user, @post)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

You can trigger this route by doing:

```
<%= link_to 'new post', new_user_post_path(current_user) %>
```

and edit:

```
<%= link_to 'edit post', edit_user_post_path(current_user, @post) %>
```

checkout: [nested resources rails api](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the best practices, but I think it makes the most sense to try and only CRUD models within their resource scope.  That said, I prefer to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and creating it through a form submission to `@model1`, but again, it's simply preference - either will work.